# EXT JS4: XML output

Tags: json, xml, extjs, extjs4

While converting JSON to XML using Sencha EXT JS4, we get XML output in below format:

```
<root>
    <tag1>
        <tag2 value="4"/>
     </tag1>
<root>
```

While our backend API accepts below format:

```
<root>
    <tag1>
        <tag2>
          <value>4</value>
        </tag2>
     </tag1>
<root>
```

i.e. instead of xml element, the value is outputted as an element attribute. Any idea how to get desired XML output?

Comment: Could you show your json.